# Proving a property of determinant in MATLAB

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matlab

I want to prove this relation of determinant in MATLAB;
$K^2 \det (KI_3-BA) = K^3 \det (KI_2-AB)$, for $A_{2×3}$ and $B_{3×2} $.But by defining symbolic variables, at the end when I subtract two sides from each other, I haven't zero but an expression such $k(ad-bc)-k(ad-bc)$! Actually, the factors don't act on in-parenthesis elements. How can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the code? This one works for me: ``A = sym('A',[2 3]); B = sym('B',[3 2]); syms K; simplify(K^2*det(K*eye(3)-B*A) - K^3*det(K*eye(2)-A*B))``

Comment: "simplify" function should do the trick... https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html

Comment: I was not similar by simplify function, by use of simplify problem solved. Thank you for your consideration. Many thanks.